# Multiple Sticky Items within using 2 separate views

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have 10 nodes and 2 views, one view named **highlighted nodes**, the other - **other nodes**

I created the concept that if a user sets one of their nodes to appear "sticky at the top of lists" then it would appear in the **highlighted nodes** view.

My second view outputs the rest of the nodes with an offset of 1 i.e. skipping the first node that I assumed "there will only be one" node that was set to sticky at the top of lists

My question is, how do I cater if two nodes are set to "sticky at the top of lists". Could you offer a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a filter, for the view **highlighted nodes**:

```
Content: Sticky at top of lists (= Yes)
```

and for the view **other nodes**:

```
Content: Sticky at top of lists (= No)
```

Comment: I've decided to adjust my solution to include your answer. The original problem defines that there could only be one node in the highlighted nodes view. So if there was 2... where would the 2nd appear? Thanks for answering anyway. I was too busy looking for the answer in the "sort" section of drupal views.